# Form always submits as GET even with POST method

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having a problem with my form submission. The code is below. When I submit, it is submitting as GET and not as POST, even though my method is post. I have tried method="POST" and method="post". What am I missing here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <?php 
            echo "POST: "; 
            print_r($_POST); 
            echo " GET :"; 
            print_r($_GET); 
        ?>

        <form role="form" name='test' method=“post” action="test2.php">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use those wacky quotes: `“post”` should look like `"post"`.

Comment: Wow.... I don't even know how those got in there. It's much more obvious outside of my text editor. Thanks! This was an hour of heartache.